# Card Drawing Probability

Tags: probability

If three cards are drawn randomly from a normal playing deck without replacement, what is the probability that two end up being black and one red? I did the problem and came up with 13/102. My Saxon book said 39/102 or 13/34. They got that by adding together the probabilities of the three color combinations, which are all equal to each other. But I don't care what order I draw those colors in. Why do they add together those three events when I only draw the three cards once?

Comment: If you picked two red and one black, the black card could have been first, second or third. You found the probability for one of these options. In other words, there are three events that give you the desired outcome.

Comment: You can describe the problem in a number of different ways.  I would personally have described this as a hypergeometric probability and would have gotten an answer of $\dfrac{\binom{26}{2}\binom{26}{1}}{\binom{52}{3}}=\dfrac{13}{34}$.  They probably described the answer where order of cards being drawn matters while my calculation treated order as irrelevant and drew them all simultaneously.  If you treated order as relevant, you'd have each of the outcomes BBR, BRB, RBB all count as having drawn two black and one red (*in any order*).

Answer (score 0):

'Without replacement' means that you draw the cards one after the other, hence the order in which the cards are drawn is important. The red card may be drawn on the first, second or third draw, so the required probability is $3\times\frac{13}{102}$.

**Edit.** You may do the same exercise by assuming the cards are drawn simultaneously, as noted by @JMoravitz in the comments. The same answer is obtained without talking about order of drawing.

Comment: "*without replacement means... hence the order...is important*"  I disagree with this.  The order is only as important as you make it be.  In *some* problems the order will be important.  In this problem, you have the option of treating it as important or as unimportant and both lead to the same final result.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have generally seen the phrase 'without replacement' being mentioned when the cards are drawn sequentially. If they are drawn simultaneously, there would be no need for mentioning that as replacement would not be possible/material.

Comment: Consider the problem where we draw all $52$ cards from a shuffled deck in a row in sequence.  If we ask the question "What is the probability that the 49th card is red?" we could, if you insisted, use the sample space of size $52!$ which describes the position of every single card in the deck and the order in which they were drawn.  It would have been much smarter however to have used a sample space of size $52$ or even better of size $2$ which describes only the result of the 49th card and chooses to ignore all other information.  We have a *choice* of what sample space to use in problems.

Comment: And it so happens that in this problem, we have the *choice* of choosing to describe the results in an aggregated sort of way, where we have chosen to ignore the exact sequence in which we saw the cards, effectively making it as though we had chosen the cards simultaneously with order not mattering.  In doing so, we get a smaller sample space and the desirable outcomes are more easily described and more conveniently counted using binomial coefficients.  We are very rarely *forced* to use a specific sample space.  We use whichever helps facilitate easy and correct calculations and explanations.

Comment: I see, using binomial coefficients makes the order immaterial here. At the same time, the actual question is why the probability $13/102$ must be added $3$ times and discussion about order here was ordained when the OP arrived at the figure $13/102$. As much as I would like to edit in your approach using binomial coefficients rendering order needless, I'm afraid I will not be able to provide a rigorous explanation as to _why_ it works.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri the difference is you are looking at the process of drawing without replacement while JMoravitz is only interested in the outcome (the final result). After choosing three cards without replacement, you have a 3-card hand. You cannot choose 3 cards without replacement and wind up with the same card twice. So, JMoravitz is only looking at 3-card hands and looking for the probability that a 3-card hand has two black and one red card.

Comment: This is the equivalent to looking at all possible ways to draw a three card hand with the desired composition.